# Black hole evaporation, mass or bit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, quantum-information

Usually when we talk about black hole evaporation, mass or energy is taken as the target and the evaporation time is computed based on mass loss in a given time period.

Is there any work to analysis the evaporation speed of black hole purely based on the degree of freedom?

How to understand how many bits are lost in a given time from an information theory point of view but not by black-body radiation?

Which one is more fundamental here, mass or bit?

PS: I am curious on this since $dm/dt = -a/m^2$ with $a$ a constant factor in the normal black hole radiation computation, this can be transformed in to  $dS/dt*(1/T)=-a$ where S is the entropy and T is the temperature. This roughly can be interpreted as "in each time step ($1/T$) the evaporation of entropy is constant". Is there a deeper reason for this? Can we derive this directly from an information point of view?

Comment: How many bits are lost due to the sun shining? Absolutely none. There is no information content in the radiation of the sun. There isn't any information content in the radiation of a black hole, either. You are merely seeing a 19th century philosophical nonsense reviewed by theoretical physicists without any sense of what "information" actually means.

Comment: Sorry, There isn't any information content in the radiation of a black hole? I do not agree with you. If you know Page's calculation or Hayden-Preskill's work on the information retrieval from black hole radiation, then you will not say this.

Comment: @igael The final stage of the radiation is not clear yet. But even this is the case, information might be a possible solution to explain it.

Comment: @igael Sorry, I mean the radiation rate of $-1/m^2$ might be correct, but the information point of view might be more fundamental. Don't you think the 'constant entropy loss' is more beautiful?

Comment: Nope, there is no information about anything in the thermal radiation of a black hole except about its mass and thus temperature. What you are seeing here is a new version of the Poincare-recurrence theorem, which was just as useless back then as the black hole information paradox is today.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But till now there is no definite answer yet. I do not think we should stop further discussion on it as far as there is debate. For me, it seems you have a very compact definition about what's science and you are very confident that all the stuff beyond your definition should not be allowed to be discussed here.

Comment: Well, I will let you get started on something smaller. We will buy a cup of coffee for you at Starbucks. I have the barista write a six figure number on it with foam. Then I will stir the coffee for a minute and hand it to you. Your task will be to tell me what that number was, since, clearly, information in this universe is not lost, right?

Comment: Black body radiation is only one possible model of black hole radiation. It does not mean it's the ground truth. At least nobody can definitely claim this.

Comment: Well, it's the only thing anybody can claim with some form of reasonable physical intuition, right now. The rest is speculation. Until you have something better, please tell me how you are going to resurrect the foam number from the stirred coffee... if you can't even do that, any claim that you can get information out of a black hole is absolutely hilarious, but it's not physics.

Comment: Let's make it even simpler. If in the cup are coco beans with two different colors, black and brown. Then the brown beans show a 6 at the surface. Then we vibrate the cup for 1 minute and number 6 disappears. Can I restore the information?

Comment: You can't even predict next week's lotto numbers, and that's just a couple dozen balls. So who in their right mind will ever claim that one can retrieve information from a system so much larger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35085/discussion-between-x-dong-and-curiousone).